# CSV2XML: How to insert additional nodes/elements

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following code that I found on another question.  It works great at reading the source CSV file and parsing it.  I need to insert additional nodes/elements into the parsed elements.  I need the ZipDateCount and ZipCount element names inserted in the specified location defined in the Desired Output example.

The code I found works great.  I can't figure out how to generate the desired result.

I've tried using a template and using another position() call.  All of my attempts have failed miserably.

I can't figure out how to isolate the fields that need to be enclosed within the additional elements.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Source data

```
Name,Description,Active,start-date,end-date,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
zip11111,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip22222,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip33333,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip44444,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip55555,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
```

Source xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="csv-data" as="xs:string">Name,Description,Active,start-date,end-date,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
zip11111,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip22222,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip33333,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip44444,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip55555,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="csv2xml">
    <Root>
        <!--Get Header-->
        <xsl:variable name="header-tokens" as="xs:string*">
          <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv-data" regex="\r\n?|\n">
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="tokenize(.,',')"/>                                        
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>                    
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv-data" regex="\r\n?|\n">
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
              <ZipCode>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                  <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </ZipCode>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <ZipCode>
      <Name>zip11111</Name>
      <Description>Zip Code 11111</Description>
      <Active>FALSE</Active>
      <start-date>3012019</start-date>
      <end-date>3312019</end-date>
      <DeliverMethod>S</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>100</Monday>
      <Tuesday>100</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>100</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>100</Thursday>
      <Friday>100</Friday>
      <Saturday>100</Saturday>
      <Sunday>100</Sunday>
      <DeliverMethod>NS</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>50</Monday>
      <Tuesday>50</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>50</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>50</Thursday>
      <Friday>50</Friday>
      <Saturday>50</Saturday>
      <Sunday>50</Sunday>
      <DeliverMethod>DM</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>35</Monday>
      <Tuesday>35</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>35</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>35</Thursday>
      <Friday>35</Friday>
      <Saturday>35</Saturday>
      <Sunday>35</Sunday>
      <DeliverMethod>D</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>20</Monday>
      <Tuesday>20</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>20</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>20</Thursday>
      <Friday>20</Friday>
      <Saturday>20</Saturday>
      <Sunday>20</Sunday>
   </ZipCode>
   <ZipCode>
      <Name>zip22222</Name>
      <Description>Zip Code 11111</Description>
      <Active>FALSE</Active>
      <start-date>3012019</start-date>
      <end-date>3312019</end-date>
      <DeliverMethod>S</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>100</Monday>
      <Tuesday>100</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>100</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>100</Thursday>
      <Friday>100</Friday>
      <Saturday>100</Saturday>
      <Sunday>100</Sunday>
      <DeliverMethod>NS</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>50</Monday>
      <Tuesday>50</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>50</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>50</Thursday>
      <Friday>50</Friday>
      <Saturday>50</Saturday>
      <Sunday>50</Sunday>
      <DeliverMethod>DM</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>35</Monday>
      <Tuesday>35</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>35</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>35</Thursday>
      <Friday>35</Friday>
      <Saturday>35</Saturday>
      <Sunday>35</Sunday>
      <DeliverMethod>D</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>20</Monday>
      <Tuesday>20</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>20</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>20</Thursday>
      <Friday>20</Friday>
      <Saturday>20</Saturday>
      <Sunday>20</Sunday>
   </ZipCode>
...
   </ZipCode>
</Root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <ZipCode>
      <Name>zip11111</Name>
      <Description>Zip Code 11111</Description>
      <Active>FALSE</Active>
    <ZipDateCount>
      <start-date>3012019</start-date>
      <end-date>3312019</end-date>
    <ZipCounts>
      <DeliverMethod>S</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>100</Monday>
      <Tuesday>100</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>100</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>100</Thursday>
      <Friday>100</Friday>
      <Saturday>100</Saturday>
      <Sunday>100</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    <ZipCounts>
      <DeliverMethod>NS</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>50</Monday>
      <Tuesday>50</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>50</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>50</Thursday>
      <Friday>50</Friday>
      <Saturday>50</Saturday>
      <Sunday>50</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    <ZipCounts>
      <DeliverMethod>DM</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>35</Monday>
      <Tuesday>35</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>35</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>35</Thursday>
      <Friday>35</Friday>
      <Saturday>35</Saturday>
      <Sunday>35</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    <ZipCounts>
      <DeliverMethod>D</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>20</Monday>
      <Tuesday>20</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>20</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>20</Thursday>
      <Friday>20</Friday>
      <Saturday>20</Saturday>
      <Sunday>20</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    </ZipDateCount>
   </ZipCode>
   <ZipCode>
      <Name>zip22222</Name>
      <Description>Zip Code 11111</Description>
      <Active>FALSE</Active>
    <ZipDateCount>
      <start-date>3012019</start-date>
      <end-date>3312019</end-date>
    <ZipCounts>   
      <DeliverMethod>S</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>100</Monday>
      <Tuesday>100</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>100</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>100</Thursday>
      <Friday>100</Friday>
      <Saturday>100</Saturday>
      <Sunday>100</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    <ZipCounts>   
      <DeliverMethod>NS</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>50</Monday>
      <Tuesday>50</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>50</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>50</Thursday>
      <Friday>50</Friday>
      <Saturday>50</Saturday>
      <Sunday>50</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    <ZipCounts>   
      <DeliverMethod>DM</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>35</Monday>
      <Tuesday>35</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>35</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>35</Thursday>
      <Friday>35</Friday>
      <Saturday>35</Saturday>
      <Sunday>35</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    <ZipCounts>   
      <DeliverMethod>D</DeliverMethod>
      <Monday>20</Monday>
      <Tuesday>20</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>20</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>20</Thursday>
      <Friday>20</Friday>
      <Saturday>20</Saturday>
      <Sunday>20</Sunday>
    </ZipCounts>
    </ZipDateCount>
   </ZipCode>
</Root>
```

Comment: Well, if the current XSLT creates `DistCodes` elements with `<DistCodes>` and you want `ZipCode` instead it should be clear how to change that. For the other changes I would suggest to run a second transformation step on the result of the CSV to XML transformation, so store that in a variable and then push it through some templates doing the transformation, it seems using `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="DeliveryMethod"` can help with that. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info for some overview.

Comment: The DistCode to ZipCode was bad example.  I thought I had updated the transformation.  I've editied it and corrected it.  Thanks for the feedback.  I'll take a look at using xsl:for-each-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of the CSV to XML transformation in a variable and then push it to some templates to perform any needed XML to XML transformation; for that particular task of wrapping any group of adjacent elements starting with `DeliverMethod` into a `ZipCounts` you can use `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="DeliverMethod"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="csv-data" as="xs:string">Name,Description,Active,start-date,end-date,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,DeliverMethod,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
zip11111,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip22222,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip33333,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip44444,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
zip55555,Zip Code 11111,FALSE,3012019,3312019,S,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,NS,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,DM,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,D,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="csv2xml">
    <Root>
        <!--Get Header-->
        <xsl:variable name="header-tokens" as="xs:string*">
          <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv-data" regex="\r\n?|\n">
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="tokenize(.,',')"/>                                        
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>  
        <xsl:variable name="csv-xml">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv-data" regex="\r\n?|\n">
              <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
                  <ZipCode>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                      <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                      </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </ZipCode>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>            
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$csv-xml/*"/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ZipCode">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="header-elements" select="Name, Description, Active"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$header-elements"/>
          <ZipDateCount>
              <xsl:variable name="date-elements" select="start-date, end-date"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$date-elements"/>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="* except ($header-elements, $date-elements)" group-starting-with="DeliverMethod">
                  <ZipCounts>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                  </ZipCounts>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
          </ZipDateCount>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6s

Comment: This works great!  Exaclty as expected.
How do I convert this to a process that will use any similarly structured file as the source?  I've tried adding a template and storing the contents of the file as a variable called "csv-data".  I then call the "csv2xml" template.  I can't get it to produce any output though.  http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpE  Thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the idea of the original code you used is to pass in the raw CSV data as a global string parameter named `csv-data` and then to don't use any XML input document but rather start the XSLT 2 processor with the named template `csv2xml` (for instance with Saxon 9 on the command line you wouldn't supply a source XML with the `-s` option but use `-it:csv2xml` to indicate the template to start with).

Comment: If you don't want a string parameter but read from a raw CSV file I would suggest to use e.g. `<xsl:param name="csv-file" as="xs:string" select="'foo.csv'"/>` and then `<xsl:param name="csv-data" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($csv-file)"/>`.

Comment: Finally, if you have the CSV data wrapped in your XML input, then the easiest change is shown in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6s/1 with e.g. `<xsl:param name="csv-data" as="xs:string" select="/"/>`.